# How to get a parameter from an XML file?

Tags: php, xml

I want to get an `href` from my XML parameters file; this is my code:

```
$linkx = $params->get('linkx'); 
echo '<a href="$linkx"><p class="bottomp"> Find More </a>';
```

What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: how is the structure of the xml file containing the url ?

Comment: `<field
     name="linkx"
     type="text"
     label="Find More Link"
     description="Link to more news" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example using [SimpleXML](http://docs.php.net/simplexml) and [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/)

```
<?php
$doc = new SimpleXMLELement( data() );
$fields = $doc->xpath('//form[@id="form2"]/field');

foreach( $fields as $f) {
    printf('name=%s, type=%s, label=%s%s', $f['name'], $f['type'], $f['label'], PHP_EOL);
}


function data() {
return <<< eot
<data>
    <form id="form1"></form>
    <form id="form2">
        <field name="linkx" type="text" label="Find More Link" description="Link to more news" />
        <field name="linky" type="text" label="..." description="---" />
    </form>
    <form id="form3"></form>
</data>
eot;
}
```

prints

```
name=linkx, type=text, label=Find More Link
name=linky, type=text, label=...
```